# Why does fs.watch log three entries per file when a new file is placed in the directory

Tags: node.js, fs

I don't know if there is some glitch in my code. I am watching a directory for new json files. fs.watch sees the file but records three entries in the log. I can't seem to figure out why.

MY CODE

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.watch('C:/Users/PCAdmin/Downloads/jsonin', function (event, filename) {
  console.log('event is: ' + event);
  if (filename) {
    console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});
```

The output:

```
LOG ENTRIES 
event is: rename
filename provided: 23456.json
event is: change
filename provided: 23456.json
event is: change
filename provided: 23456.json
```

Comment: Can you describe the thing that's populating that directory?  What you see likely has a lot to do with the thing that's putting the files there in the first place.

Comment: Right now I am just copying a test file from another directory and pasting into the watched directory.

Comment: So after much research it appears that fs.watch is picking up  the ReadDirectoryChangesW FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES

Answer (score 0):

So after much research it appears that fs.watch is picking up the ReadDirectoryChangesW FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES

To alleviate the problem, I added an extra if statement to limit the responses to rename which will catch the file name being added

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.watch('C:/Users/PCAdmin/Downloads/jsonin', function (event, filename) {
  if (event ==='rename') {
  console.log('event is: ' + event);

  if (filename) {
    console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
    return;
  }
  }
});
```